# Node.js Compression Proxy for Data saving

Tags: node.js, http, https, proxy, compression

I am looking for a Proxy Server in Node.js which compresses the data I receive through internet similar to Google's Data Saver extension. I want the server to compress the data of every process in my computer which uses internet. I am asking this because I want to reduce my Data usage so that I can reduce my costs for Internet. I don't know whether it is possible or not. Google's Data Saver only compresses http requests. I want the server to compress https as well.

So basically if I request a webpage, then it should pass through the server, the server requests the same webpage, compresses it and then sends me back.

Any ideas on how to do this in node.js. Any kind of suggestions are welcome. I heard about Gzip but it is specific to your own created websites. I want the server to sit in between me and the requested website and compress data. If it is possible, can I achieve high compression ratio ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have a look into this [filternet - A simple way to filter http in node.js](https://github.com/axiak/filternet)

1. compression for both directions (deflate and gzip, no sdch)
2. supports HTTP
3. and HTTPS